# Libgdx - How to implement loading screen in Android Launcher using ads

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services, screen

So I've created a game using Libgdx and the load times were practically non-existent, recently I added a Facebook leaderboard using the GDXFacebook extension which added a small overhead when loading up the app as it will auto login when loading but nothing that really effected load times. Now using and implementation from Libgdx I have added ads through Google play services to the main page of the game but it has made it so the initial load times is now a good 5 seconds.

My question is is there away to add the loading image to the android launcher class while it is loading to the main screen?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my Android launcher class and main game class.

Android Launcher:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements        IActivityRequestHandler {

private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;


private AdView adView;

protected Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case SHOW_ADS: {
                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
            case HIDE_ADS: {
                adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useCompass = false;
    config.useAccelerometer = false;

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);


    load(config, layout);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();


}


private void load(AndroidApplicationConfiguration config, RelativeLayout layout){
    // Create the libgdx View
    View gameView = initializeForView(new Game(this), config);

    String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Create and setup the AdMob view
    adView = new AdView(this); // Put in your secret key here
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

/** if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }**/

    //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().setLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider)).build();
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Add the libgdx view
    layout.addView(gameView);

    // Add the AdMob view
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adView.setY(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM - 80);

    showAds(false);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

}



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) adView.resume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) adView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void showAds(boolean show) {
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
}

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
public Action getIndexApiAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName("AndroidLauncher Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
            .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
            .build();
    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
    client.disconnect();
}
```

Game Class:

```
public class Game implements ApplicationListener{

private int m_ScreenWidth;
private int m_ScreenHeight;

private IActivityRequestHandler requestHandler;


private GameScreen m_GameScreen;
private MenuScreen m_Menu;
private HighScoreScreen m_HighScores;
private RankingsScreen m_RankingScreen;
private Input m_Input;
private Assets m_Assets;

private ShapeRenderer m_ShapeRenderer;
private SpriteBatch m_BatchRenderer;
private OrthographicCamera m_Camera;
private boolean m_Loaded;

public enum State {
    READY, MENU, RUNNING, PAUSED, HIGHSCORE, RANKINGS
}

private State m_State;

public Game(IActivityRequestHandler handler){
    requestHandler = handler;
}

@Override
public void create() {

    m_ScreenWidth = 360;
    m_ScreenHeight = 640;


    m_Camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    m_Camera.setToOrtho(false, 360, 640);
    m_Camera.position.set(m_ScreenWidth / 2, m_ScreenHeight / 2, 0);
    m_Camera.update();

    m_ShapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    m_BatchRenderer = new SpriteBatch();
    m_BatchRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(m_Camera.combined);
    m_ShapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(m_Camera.combined);

    m_Loaded = false;

    m_Assets = new Assets();
    m_Assets.loadAssets();

    while (!m_Loaded) {
        if (m_Assets.getAssetManager().update()) {
            m_Loaded = true;
        }
    }


    m_GameScreen = new GameScreen(m_ScreenWidth, m_ScreenHeight, m_BatchRenderer, m_ShapeRenderer, m_Camera, this, m_Assets);
    m_Menu = new MenuScreen(m_ScreenWidth, m_ScreenHeight, m_BatchRenderer, m_ShapeRenderer, m_Camera, this, m_Assets);
    m_HighScores = new HighScoreScreen(m_ScreenWidth, m_ScreenHeight, m_BatchRenderer, m_ShapeRenderer, m_Camera, this, m_Assets);
    m_RankingScreen = new RankingsScreen(m_ScreenWidth, m_ScreenHeight, m_BatchRenderer, m_ShapeRenderer, m_Camera, this, m_Assets);
    m_Input = new Input(this, m_GameScreen, m_HighScores, m_Menu, m_RankingScreen);


    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(m_Input);

    m_RankingScreen.autologin();

    setState(State.MENU);
}

@Override
public void render() {

    switch (m_State) {
        case PAUSED:
            m_GameScreen.renderBackground();
            m_GameScreen.renderPaused();
            break;
        case HIGHSCORE:
            m_GameScreen.renderBackground();
            m_HighScores.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
            break;
        case MENU:
            m_Menu.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
            break;
        case READY:
            m_GameScreen.renderReady(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
            break;
        case RUNNING:
            m_GameScreen.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
            break;
        case RANKINGS:
            m_RankingScreen.render();
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void dispose() {
    m_RankingScreen.logout();
    m_ShapeRenderer.dispose();
    m_BatchRenderer.dispose();
    m_Assets.dispose();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

public State getState() {
    return m_State;
}

public void setState(State state) {
    if(state == State.MENU) {
        m_Menu.resetEnemies();
        requestHandler.showAds(true);
    }
    else if(state == State.RANKINGS) {

        m_RankingScreen.refresh();
        requestHandler.showAds(false);
    } else{
        requestHandler.showAds(false);
    }
    m_State = state;
}

public void resetGame() {
    m_GameScreen.reset();
    m_State = State.READY;
}

public void closeGame() {
    Gdx.app.exit();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    if (m_State == State.RUNNING)
        setState(State.PAUSED);

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    if (!m_Loaded) {
        while (!m_Loaded) {
            if (m_Assets.getAssetManager().update()) {
                m_Loaded = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```